# compact and connected set in open subspace

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

This is a very simple question but I want to make sure I did not miss something basic.

My question is, Assume $X$ be a topological space and $Y$ be an open subspace of $X$. Let $B$ be a compact and connected subset of $Y$ ( means , with respect to  relative topology $Y$). Then, $B$ is compact and connected with respect relative topology $X.$

Is that true?   I did not include any argument since it would be relatively easy unless I missed something. Please correct If I am wrong. Any help will be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Is there a typo? Do you mean to ask "Is $B$ compact and connected with respect to the topology on $X$?". If that was your question then this is true. In fact the subspace $Y$ does not have to be open in $X$.

Comment: @MichaelCohen, I fixed. You are right . I thought $Y$ needs to be open to $B$ compact in $X$

Comment: @00GB: No, compactness of $B$ is a property of $B$ and its topology; if $B$ is compact as a space, it is compact in any space in which it is embedded.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, So, I can not say $B$ is compact in subspace $Y$. or what do you mean by NO?

Comment: @00GB: I mean that $Y$ does not need to be open: if $B$ is compact in $Y$, it is compact in itself and in any space in which it may be embedded, including $X$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, my thought process was thing about considering  open cover for $B$ in the big topology, $X$. This is why I thought $Y$ needs to be open. You said, compact in itself so the open sets in the open cover must be open in relative topology with respect to $B$ right ?

Comment: @00GB: If $\mathscr{C}$ is the cover, all that matters is that $C\cap B$ is open in $B$ for each $C\in\mathscr{C}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, if you need to consider open cover for $B$ should be in this form $B\cap C$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I am very sure you are familar with notation of continuum subsets of $\Bbb R$. Based what you explain to me. Let $X$ be topological spaces and $Y$ be subspace. If $B\subset Y$ is continuum in $Y$ then $B$ is continuum in $X$.  By continuum is compact and connected.

Comment: @00GB: Yes: like compactness, connectedness is independent of the surrounding space. If $B$ is a continuum, then it is a continuum in any space in which it is embedded. Here it’s a continuum in $Y$, so it’s simply a continuum, full stop, and therefore it’s a continuum in $X$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, Thank you very much. I took complete courses in topology but this is my first time one told the idea of like what you did, " it is any space in which it is embedded.

Comment: @00GB: You’re very welcome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122699/discussion-between-00gb-and-brian-m-scott).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compactness or connectedness of $B$ does *not* depend om which space it is embedded in (or was a subspace of initially). So $B$ compact in $Y$ just is $B$ compact period. So also compact as a subspace of $X$. Ditto for connectedness. The proofs are not hard or deep, but they're often omitted, leaving students with the faulty idea that "$B$ compact in $Y$" is somehow different from "$B$ compact in $X$". It's not, it's just $B$ is compact as a space in its own right (so in the subspace topology it inherits upon definition, as it were).